# Why doesn't WP update my .htaccess file?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

Before I begin, I do *not* have WordPress having permissions to update the `.htaccess` file. That's not what this is about. I'm full aware of that.

My problem is WP generates the same file every time for me to copy to my `.htaccess` file. With default permissions:

("Post Name" setting:)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

("Numeric" setting:)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

***Same exact thing.*** That setup works perfectly when the "default" setting is used, but it's not working now. I've tried copying it before and after I save the changes, but it's still the same.

Why isn't this working? I believe this is the right file setup (I access it with `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/wordpress/`)...

`/var/www/html/wordpress$ sudo nano .htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty Permalink parsing happens internally within WordPress, *any* permalink setting other than default uses the same .htaccess rules, because all variants simply direct any request which is not a physical directory or file to WordPress.